# Twilio Code Not Working When App Deployed to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, twilio, apscheduler

I use twilio and apscheduler to send text notifications and the code worked locally. However, when I deploy app.py to heroku, the twilio code does not work. Do I need to do an extra step when deploying for twilio to work?

Relevant code:

Adding job to scheduler

```
if datetime.now(tz=tz) <= d-timedelta(days=2):
    trigger = DateTrigger(run_date=d-timedelta(days=2), timezone=tz)

    scheduler.add_job(send_sms_reminder, trigger=trigger, id=str(slot_id), args=[slot_id], 
    misfire_grace_time=60*2)

if datetime.now(tz=tz) <= d.replace(hour=7, minute=0):
    trigger = DateTrigger(run_date=d.replace(hour=7, minute=00), timezone=tz)

    scheduler.add_job(send_sms_reminder, trigger=trigger,
    id=str(slot.slot_id)+"*", args=[slot.slot_id], misfire_grace_time=60)
```

Code for sending text

```
def send_sms_reminder(slot_id):

    s = Session()
    slot = s.query(Slots).filter_by(slot_id=slot_id).first()
    event = s.query(Events).filter_by(event_id=slot.event_id).first()
    employee = Profile.query.filter_by(username=slot.client_username).first()
    s.close()

    print("Sending message at:", datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))

    body = "Hello {name}! You have an appointment with {comp} at {time} on {date}".format(
     name=employee.first_name, comp=event.employer, time=slot.start.strftime('%H:%M%p'), 
     date=event.date.strftime("%A, %b %d"))

    message = client.messages \
    .create(
       body=body,
       from_=twilio_number,
       to="+1" + employee.phone_number
     )
```

Comment: So the twilio code works on heroku. It is apscheduler that is not working.

Comment: the scheduler jobs are not being executed even though the jobs are added to scheduler.